# Comparing linear regressions with a factor and lagged predictors, using R

Tags: r, curve-fitting, linear-regression

There is a nice piece of R code for fitting and visualising alternative linear models [at www.alastairsanderson.com/R/tutorials/linear-regression-with-a-factor/](http://www.alastairsanderson.com/R/tutorials/linear-regression-with-a-factor/). How do I possibly generalise this framework to allow for lagged predictors, e.g., by using dyn or dynlm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dyn)
library(ggplot2)

forms.ch <- c(
     "y ~ x",
     "y ~ class / x", 
     "y ~ class / Lag(x, 0:1)", 
     "y ~ class / Lag(x, 0:2)"
)
forms <- sapply(forms.ch, as.formula)
Lag <- function(x, k = 1) lag(x, -k)

# L is a list of zoo objects which is fit to each formula
L <- lapply(mydata, zoo, order.by = mydata$x)
models <- lapply(forms, dyn$lm, data = L)

# create zero width zoo object, width0, which is merged with fitted.  fitted would
# otherwise be shorter than mydata (since we can't fit points at beginning due to 
# lack of laggged points at boundary).  Also we convert mydata$x to numeric, 
# from integer, to avoid warnings later on.
width0 <- zoo(, as.numeric(mydata$x))
models.sum <- lapply(models, function(x) 
    data.frame(mydata, 
        fitted = coredata(merge(fitted(x), width0)),
        strip = paste(format(formula(x)), "AIC:", round(AIC(x), 1)),
        formula = format(formula(x))
    )
)
models.long <- na.omit(do.call(rbind, models.sum))
models.long$class[ models.long$formula == forms.ch[1] ] <- NA # first model has no class
ggplot(models.long, aes(x, y, colour = class)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y = fitted)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    facet_wrap(~ strip)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is even nicer, and does encourage me to read more about your package for time series regression, but could you please complete your answer by showing how it works with ggplot --- it throws errors and warnings at me. Thanks.

Comment: Nice! We're almost there. I have to use models.long <- na.omit(do.call(rbind, models.sum)) to get rid of ggplot's warnings. More importantly, if one adds "y~x" to the top of the list of formulae, then plotting is no longer right. To fight this manually, models.long$class[1:50]<-NA will suffice. Could you please incorporate a generic fix for this into your answer. And that would be it, I think, thanks heaps.

Comment: OK. Have made these changes.