# Lagged linear model to identify correlation in age frequency data

Tags: r, regression, lag, lm

I have this data and I'm trying to do a lagged linear regression in r to determine if the number of YOY's is significantly correlated to numbers of 1 year olds the next year, and 2 year olds the year after that... etc...

data:

```
structure(list(Year = c("2008", "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", 
"2013", "2014", "2015", "2016", "2017", "2018", "2007", "2007", 
"2007", "2007", "2008", "2008", "2008", "2009", "2009", "2009", 
"2009", "2009", "2009", "2009", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
"2010", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", "2011", 
"2011", "2011", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", "2012", 
"2012", "2012", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", "2013", 
"2013", "2013", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", "2014", 
"2014", "2014", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", 
"2015", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2016", "2016", "2016", "2016", 
"2016", "2016", "2016", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", "2017", 
"2017", "2017", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2018", 
"2018", "2018"), Age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("0", "1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"), class = "factor"), n = c(166, 
28, 34, 77, 170, 18, 3, 22, 43, 50, 151, 1, 8, 17, 1, 4, 19, 
1, 1, 46, 37, 52, 5, 1, 1, 19, 41, 15, 16, 1, 1, 13, 4, 26, 12, 
11, 1, 1, 1, 1, 87, 15, 13, 27, 13, 17, 1, 1, 32, 30, 3, 4, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 24, 15, 23, 6, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 18, 13, 31, 28, 3, 3, 
6, 1, 4, 6, 1, 5, 9, 1, 1, 1, 16, 16, 8, 1, 1, 4, 1, 12, 4, 7, 
2, 1, 2, 1), id = c("YOY", "YOY", "YOY", "YOY", "YOY", "YOY", 
"YOY", "YOY", "YOY", "YOY", "YOY", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult", 
"Adult", "Adult", "Adult", "Adult")), row.names = c(NA, -95L), class = "data.frame")
```

I made  great plot that shows it sure does look like there is something here. Not perfect but some kind of relationship.

```
# Frequencey density plot of ages over year
ggplot(wi.age.count, aes(x=Year, y=Age)) + 
  geom_point(aes(cex = n, color = id)) +
  #scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") +
  labs(title = "Age frequency plot", subtitle = "Hogfish", y = "Age", x = "Year") +
  scale_size(range = c(1,10), breaks=c(1,2, 5, 10, 20, 40, 60, 80, 110, 150)) +
  theme_bw() + theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                     panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

As a bonus, if anyone knows how to put diagonal lines through to data from age, year to age+1, year+1 etc... that would be great.

My lagged linear code is terrible and I've spent weeks reading literature and stack questions. I can show you more of my failed attempts if you'd like.

here is one attempt

```
# linear model
l.fit <- lm(wi.age.count$Year ~ wi.age.count$n + lag(wi.age.count$Year, +1)); par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
AIC.l.fit <- signif(AIC(l.fit), digits = 3)
plot(wi.age.count$Year ~ wi.age.count$n, pch = 2, type="b", xlab = 'Year', ylab = 'Age Frequency', xlim=range(age.hog$Year), ylim=range(c(0,age.hog$n)), main="Hogfish")
abline(l.fit, lwd=3, lty=3); legend (0, 700, paste("AIC =", AIC.l.fit), bty = 'n')
hist(residuals(l.fit), xlab='Residuals', main='Quality check')
summary(l.fit)
```

I'm not even really sure which is most appropriate, lagged linear model or an ARIMA or `acf()` or something entirely different. One of the issues is that I have 3 dimensions... Year, Age, and number at age. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sources I have tried to emulate, on top of all the scientific literature.

[R adding lagged variable to sarima model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53661185/r-adding-lagged-variable-to-sarima-model)

[R - predicting simple dyn model with one lag term](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11215868/r-predicting-simple-dyn-model-with-one-lag-term)

[Iteratively forecasting dyn models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856555/iteratively-forecasting-dyn-models)

[Issue when attempting to run a Distributed Lag model in R using dynlm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58390129/issue-when-attempting-to-run-a-distributed-lag-model-in-r-using-dynlm)

[Comparing linear regressions with a factor and lagged predictors, using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747758/comparing-linear-regressions-with-a-factor-and-lagged-predictors-using-r)

[R: How to fit a time series model such as "Y(t) = αX + βY(t-1)"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40384774/r-how-to-fit-a-time-series-model-such-as-yt-%ce%b1x-%ce%b2yt-1)

[Lagged regression in R: determining the optimal lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62199626/lagged-regression-in-r-determining-the-optimal-lag)

The data should look like this... without the first couple years.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am adding another answer upon your comment on 7.27.2020. The plot does not have numbers, but it gives some idea about the numbers that I should have in the IVS matrix. Please try the following code and see if it makes sense.

```
tmp = wi.age.count[order(wi.age.count$Age), ]
ivs = reshape(tmp[which(tmp$Age != 0), -4], direction = "wide", idvar = "Year", timevar = "Age")
ivs[is.na(ivs)] = 0

> ivs
   Year n.1 n.2 n.3 n.4 n.5 n.6 n.7 n.8 n.9
13 2007   8  17   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
16 2008   4  19   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
20 2009  46  37  52   5   1   1   0   0   0
26 2010  19  41  15  16   0   0   0   0   1
32 2011  13   4  26  12  11   1   1   1   0
41 2012  87  15  13  27  13  17   1   0   0
49 2013  32  30   3   4   1   1   1   0   0
57 2014  24  15  23   6   2   1   2   2   0
66 2015  18  13  31  28   3   3   6   0   1
74 2016   4   6   1   5   9   1   0   0   1
82 2017  16  16   8   1   1   4   0   0   0
89 2018  12   4   7   2   1   2   1   0   0
```

This is your ivs matrix. Does that look correct?

Everything else is the same. Here is your dv matrix:

```
dv = wi.age.count[which(wi.age.count$id == "YOY"), c(1, 3)]

> dv
   Year   n
1  2008 166
2  2009  28
3  2010  34
4  2011  77
5  2012 170
6  2013  18
7  2014   3
8  2015  22
9  2016  43
10 2017  50
11 2018 151
```

And your formula with three lags.

```
formula = ""
for (i in 2:4) formula = paste(formula, "+",  names(ivs)[i])
formula = paste("n ~", substr(formula, 4, nchar(formula)))

> formula
[1] "n ~ n.1 + n.2 + n.3"
```

And here are the results:

```
l.fit = lm(formula, merge(dv, ivs))
AIC.l.fit <- signif(AIC(l.fit), digits = 3)
summary(l.fit)

Call:
lm(formula = formula, data = merge(dv, ivs))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-60.367 -38.028   8.698  23.763  96.257 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  99.8976    36.1761   2.761    0.028 *
n.1           1.1059     0.8388   1.318    0.229  
n.2          -1.7339     1.5773  -1.099    0.308  
n.3          -1.6346     1.2932  -1.264    0.247  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 59.48 on 7 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3731,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1044 
F-statistic: 1.389 on 3 and 7 DF,  p-value: 0.3233

> AIC.l.fit
[1] 126
```

Comment: The matrix looks perfect on this one. And I did't need to add the zeros for NA's it runs fine without them, Thank You! So in order to change the lags I only need to adjust the 2:4? And just to confirm, this is comparing the YOY years with all the age 1 adults the next year, and not including the first year? I need to compare to each age but one year later at each step. Thanks.

Comment: Correct. You only need to adjust 2:4 to change the lags.

Comment: and to confirm this is comparing 2008 YOY with 2009 age1, 2010 age2, and so on... then 2009 YOY with 2010 age.1 and 2011 age2... and so on, for the whole data set. In other words it should not be using same year for the next age up. I'm trying to verify whether high YOY years correlate to higher adult abundance in progressively later years.

Comment: Can you contact me via LinkedIn link in my profile?

Comment: I've sent you a connection request. Thank you for the offer.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
Years = sort(unique(as.numeric(wi.age.count$Year)))
ivs = data.frame(Year = NA)
for (i in 1:(length(Years)-1)) {
    ivs$dum = NA
    names(ivs)[ncol(ivs)] = paste("n.", i, sep="")
}

i = 0
while (i < length(Years)) {
    i = i + 1
    tmp = data.frame(Year = Years[i])
    j = i
    while (j < length(Years)) {
        j = j + 1
        tmp$dum = 0
        if (nrow(wi.age.count[which(wi.age.count$Year == Years[j] & wi.age.count$Age == Years[j] - Years[i]), ]) > 0) {
            tmp$dum = wi.age.count[which(wi.age.count$Year == Years[j] & wi.age.count$Age == Years[j] - Years[i]), ]$n
        }
        names(tmp)[ncol(tmp)] = paste("n.", j - i, sep="")
    }
    k = 0
    while (k < i - 1) {
        k = k + 1
        tmp$dum = NA
        names(tmp)[ncol(tmp)] = paste("n.", j - i + k, sep="")
    }
    ivs = rbind(ivs, tmp)
}
ivs = ivs[-1, ]
ivs = ivs[-(nrow(ivs)), ]
ivs[is.na(ivs)] = 0

dv = wi.age.count[which(wi.age.count$id == "YOY"), c(1, 3)]

formula = ""
for (i in 2:4) formula = paste(formula, "+",  names(ivs)[i])
formula = paste("n ~", substr(formula, 4, nchar(formula)))
l.fit = lm(formula, merge(dv, ivs))
AIC.l.fit <- signif(AIC(l.fit), digits = 3)
```

Let me explain what I do here. You said you wanted a linear model to determine if the number of YOY's are correlated with numbers of 1 year olds next year, 2 year olds the other year and so on. So, I first create the independent variables with the following lines:

```
Years = sort(unique(as.numeric(wi.age.count$Year)))
ivs = data.frame(Year = NA)
for (i in 1:(length(Years)-1)) {
    ivs$dum = NA
    names(ivs)[ncol(ivs)] = paste("n.", i, sep="")
}

i = 0
while (i < length(Years)) {
    i = i + 1
    tmp = data.frame(Year = Years[i])
    j = i
    while (j < length(Years)) {
        j = j + 1
        tmp$dum = 0
        if (nrow(wi.age.count[which(wi.age.count$Year == Years[j] & wi.age.count$Age == Years[j] - Years[i]), ]) > 0) {
            tmp$dum = wi.age.count[which(wi.age.count$Year == Years[j] & wi.age.count$Age == Years[j] - Years[i]), ]$n
        }
        names(tmp)[ncol(tmp)] = paste("n.", j - i, sep="")
    }
    k = 0
    while (k < i - 1) {
        k = k + 1
        tmp$dum = NA
        names(tmp)[ncol(tmp)] = paste("n.", j - i + k, sep="")
    }
    ivs = rbind(ivs, tmp)
}
ivs = ivs[-1, ]
ivs[is.na(ivs)] = 0


> ivs
   Year n.1 n.2 n.3 n.4 n.5 n.6 n.7 n.8 n.9 n.10 n.11
2  2007   4  37  15  12  13   1   2   0   1    0    0
3  2008  46  41  26  27   1   1   6   0   0    0    0
4  2009  19   4  13   4   2   3   0   0   0    0    0
5  2010  13  15   3   6   3   1   0   0   0    0    0
6  2011  87  30  23  28   9   4   1   0   0    0    0
7  2012  32  15  31   5   1   2   0   0   0    0    0
8  2013  24  13   1   1   1   0   0   0   0    0    0
9  2014  18   6   8   2   0   0   0   0   0    0    0
10 2015   4  16   7   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0
11 2016  16   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0
12 2017  12   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0
```

Here, *n.1* is the number of 1 year olds next year, *n.2* is the number of 2 year olds the other year and so on.

I also create a data frame that has only the dependent variable:

```
dv = wi.age.count[which(wi.age.count$id == "YOY"), c(1, 3)]
> dv
   Year   n
1  2008 166
2  2009  28
3  2010  34
4  2011  77
5  2012 170
6  2013  18
7  2014   3
8  2015  22
9  2016  43
10 2017  50
11 2018 151
```

I merge *ivs* (i.e., the first data frame that I created) and *dv* (the second data frame) when estimating the model. And here is your model:

But, let us create the formula first. I don't know how many lags you want. So, I create a formula that takes 3 lags as the independent variables. You can change the formula if you want by changing *2:4* in the for loop.

```
formula = ""
for (i in 2:4) formula = paste(formula, "+",  names(ivs)[i])
formula = paste("n ~", substr(formula, 4, nchar(formula)))

> formula
[1] "n ~ n.1 + n.2 + n.3"
```

And here is your model:

```
l.fit = lm(formula, merge(dv, ivs))
AIC.l.fit <- signif(AIC(l.fit), digits = 3)
summary(l.fit)

Call:
lm(formula = formula, data = merge(dv, ivs))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-40.389 -29.713  -0.262  25.390  44.063 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)  13.0023    19.8713   0.654   0.5372  
n.1          -0.5888     0.7834  -0.752   0.4807  
n.2           1.1125     1.5050   0.739   0.4877  
n.3           4.2888     1.5825   2.710   0.0351 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 38.25 on 6 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.727, Adjusted R-squared:  0.5905 
F-statistic: 5.326 on 3 and 6 DF,  p-value: 0.03967

> AIC.l.fit
[1] 106
```

Comment: Wow you are like a coding wizard. I had to change the class of Year in dv to numeric, but otherwise it worked.

Comment: I'm wondering what may have caused my different results? 
```Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-59.418 -35.052   1.324  19.547 108.672 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  42.3280    26.8664   1.576    0.159
n.1          -0.8851     1.1852  -0.747    0.480
n.2           0.5324     2.2762   0.234    0.822
n.3           4.1035     2.4094   1.703    0.132

Residual standard error: 58.28 on 7 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3982, Adjusted R-squared:  0.1402 
F-statistic: 1.544 on 3 and 7 DF,  p-value: 0.2858```

Comment: I think it is because your model is not correct. You have: lm(wi.age.count$Year ~ wi.age.count$n + lag(wi.age.count$Year, +1)). In this model, the DV is Year, not the number (i.e., n). Also, IVs are n and lagged Year.

Comment: I meant when I ran you model I got different results than you did.

Comment: Also do you think this is the best approach to this question?

Comment: I am not very familiar with ARIMA or act() models. So, I don't know whether this is the best approach to this question.

Comment: Upon closer examination it appears that the data did not populate the matrix correctly, there should not be any 0 values in the matrix as that is an age. There should be more ages near the middle and end years.

Comment: I added a plot of how the data looks. it looks like the matrix you created wasn't populated correctly. Could you help with this?

Comment: You said you are looking for any correlation between the number of YOY's and the numbers of 1-year-olds next year, 2-year-olds the other year, and so on.

Ex. Year = 2009. The # of YOY's in 2009 is 28. Then, the # of 1-year-olds next year, which should be 2010, is 19; the # of  2-year-olds the other year, which should be 2011, is 4, and the # of 3-year-olds the other year, which should be 2012, is 13. And so on. Thus, the row in the IV matrix for Year = 2009: n = 28, n.1 = 19, n.2 = 4, n.3 = 13, ...   Correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218713/discussion-between-johnny5ish-and-haci-duru).